# Convert .iso to .qcow2

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

I would like to convert windows .iso to .qcow2 format and use in openstack.

Tried using vbox:
https://www.virtualbox.org/
Not sure how to add cloud-init package to the OS, configure grub (steps 11&12)

Also tried using qemu-img commands in windows using ref https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/
able to convert image to .qcow2 format but when i upload image to openstack and launch instance. It got stuck at booting.

Comment: Glance support iso files. Why would you convert it to qcow2?

Answer (score 7):

```
brew/apt install qemu
qemu-img convert xxx.iso xxx.qcow2
```

Updated at May 18, 2023

It surprised me that the post still alive after years.

And the below comment answered the updated question correctly. `qemu` works fine, tho Google compute engine OS detection does not able run it. That's why it failed on them.

Comment: `qemu` seems to be still able to run the converted image as when you `dd` the iso over a disc, while apparently google compute engine OS detection does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install it first before converting it, try to install it on virtualbox and then convert virtualbox image to qcow2.

Hope it will help

Comment: I have installed windows image in virtual box, while installing  i have selected .qcow2 format.

Comment: You might try to install in qemu maybe, or debug your curent image with qemu.

Answer (score 0):

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 virtio-win.iso virtio-win.qcow2
```